# UserForm Texbox input

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have a Userform with several TextBoxes used to enter data into corresponding cells. I want these TextBoxes to show the value already in the cell like so:

TextBox1.Value = Range("B3").Value

But I want the TextBox to show a "default" value if that cell is blank: i.e., "Last Name" etc.

Can anybody give me an idea of how to change my code to accomplish this? I also have ComboBoxes that I want to do the same thing, but I think I can adapt one to the other with a just a little help here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may try `If Not Range("B3").Text = "" then TextBox1.Text= Range("B3").Text Else TextBox1.Text="The text you need"` You should put it into a `UserForm_Initialize` event

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016, if it makes a difference. Sorry about that.

Comment: That was beautiful! Thank you so much for sharing - even if I'm a little embarrassed by how quickly you got it!

Comment: Set your default value directly in design-mode. Click the `TextBox` > Navigate to the `Value` property > Assign a value, e.g.: `"Last Name"`. Now when you use the `UserForm_Initialize` event, you can check if `Range("B3").Value <> ""` and act accordingly. This is just a small edit to what Vitaliy talked about.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that one too!